# Migrating credit cards from one account to another in Stripe

Tags: stripe

I have a Stripe account with multiple customers under a single account. Now I need to migrate a customer's cards from one account to another.

Example:
A and B are customers of Stripe. How can I migrate A and B into a single account for A? (i.e., I need to transfer all the B customer cards to the A customer)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Stripe's documentation](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-migrate-to-a-new-stripe-account), you can [contact them](https://support.stripe.com/email) to request a one-time copy of customer data across accounts so you don't have to ask your users to re-enter their credit card details.

Based on this it doesn't look like Stripe offers anyway for you to migrate this data yourself.